# Unable to handle the element when it is not in the Visible Screen

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium throws an No Element found exception, when the element is not in the Visible screen. Its works only when I Scroll down the page using Autoit or manually.

Even though currently I am using AutoIt to scroll down the page and locating the elements, but I don't think so, it will work for all types of resolutions screens.

Selenium Version: 2.41.0
Chrome Version: 47.0.2526.80

Note: My Application works only in Chrome Browser

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, since `Selenium Webdriver` tries to simulate real users, it cannot interact with elements which are invisible/hidden. First you can move to the element using `Actions` and then simply put a check for the visibility of elements, something like below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By by);
Actions action = new Action(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).WhateverActionYouWantToDoOnWebElement;
```

Then you can perform whatever action you want to perform.

Comment: I don't think he's having issues with visibility as hidden or overlapped, I think what he means is he needs to scroll to the element.

Comment: Yeah, if he is having issues in scrolling than he can try above solution.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response...@ Boris, i don't have any problem with scrolling down the page.. but anyway I will try to use the idea what @Paras has suggested and let you know guys..

Comment: @pArAs the idea what you have suggested is not working for me. will paste the code below. please let me know your thoughts.. public void Clear(String Locator) {
  
  this.driver = Session.getDriver();
  
  WebElement el = this.element;
  
      Actions builder = new Actions(this.driver);
       builder.moveToElement( el );
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(this.element));
      builder.perform();
      this.element = findElement(Locator);
  this.element.clear();

 }

Comment: @Thippana, the idea is to first move the focus to the element and then check the visibility condition, b'coz in this case it would be like an alternative to scroll and it would just find the desired element on any screen resolution. You aren't doing it correctly, move your statement `builder.perform()` on top of `WebDriverWait` statement and then try to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your element at the beginning of the page, for example in the first visible `div`, using `jQuery` as shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) with the `prepend` method

```
$( ".div_class" ).prepend( $( "h2" ) ); 
//put the h2 element at the beginning of the div with class "div_class"
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/webdriver-can-i-inject-a-jquery-script-for-a-page-that-isnt-using-jquery)